# repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest error

Tags: android, python

I tried downloading the android source code as followed in the steps of https://source.android.com/source/downloading

but in the  step:

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
```

I get the following error.

> warning: Python 3 support is currently experimental. YMMV. Please use
>   Python 2.6 - 2.7 instead. Traceback (most recent call last):    File
>   "/home/marios/bin/repo", line 883, in 
>       main(sys.argv[1:])
>
> File "/home/marios/bin/repo", line 851, in main
>       _Init(args, gitc_init=(cmd == 'gitc-init'))    File "/home/marios/bin/repo", line 337, in _Init
>       _CheckGitVersion()    File "/home/marios/bin/repo", line 391, in _CheckGitVersion
>       ver_act = ParseGitVersion(ver_str)    File "/home/marios/bin/repo", line 361, in ParseGitVersion
>       if not ver_str.startswith('git version '): TypeError: startswith first arg must be bytes or a tuple of bytes, not str

Why?

Comment: Install python27 and call repo file as following: 'python2.7 repo ........'. But make sure that you are in "/home/marios/bin/" directory

Comment: have you git sol for this ?

Answer (score -1):

You are using Python 3. You must use Python version 2.6-2.7. Please visit [python.org](https://www.python.org) to learn how to install the correction version of Python on your system.